# Error while working on trigger

Tags: trigger

When an account is created automatically opportunity should be created. I have posted my code please let me know where I am facing this error.

Error facing is:

> Error: Invalid Data. 
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Apex trigger CreateOpp caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CreateOpp: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Stage, Close Date]: [Stage, Close Date]: Trigger.CreateOpp: line 13, column 1

```
trigger CreateOpp on Account (before insert,after insert) {
List<Opportunity> opp = new List<Opportunity>();

for(Account a: Trigger.New){

Opportunity op = new Opportunity();

        op.AccountId=a.id;
        op.Name= 'New Account';
        op.Type = 'Prospect';
        opp.add(op);
}
insert opp;
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Let me get my crystal ball........."Required Fields are Missing: [StageName], [CloseDate]" ??

Comment: Now that you posted the error, what are you having trouble understanding from the error message?

Comment: @Eric Not even close, you totally got the brackets wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So we do not have yet another question that is answered in comments:

The error message can be broken down into two parts:

1. Error Type - REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING
2. Specific details - [Stage, Close Date]

This means that you are missing the fields `Stage` and `CloseDate` in your record that you are inserting.

**Resolution**: Populate those values as appropriate in the records that you are trying to insert.

As with all error message review them and update your code so the error condition no longer exists. If you find an error message unhelpful, it would be easier to answer your question if you let us know what about the error message you do not understand

*Side Note* You will see we all had a bit of fun with your question. Please do not take it as directed at you. We all start somewhere, learn from the comments and take many of them in jest yet taking the context seriously.

Comment: @Satyam - If the answer solved your problem, please accept the answer. Questions with accepted answers help the entire community.